# How to display variable from a class to another class

Tags: android, dart, flutter

How to display variable from a  class to another class
    I want to display variable "text" from Helper class to displaydata class how to do it.
    and here is my code..

```
void main() {
  Helper.getData('Hello World!');
} 

class Helper {
  static getData(String someText){
    var text = someText
  }
}

class displaydata{

}
```

Comment: `text` is a variable local to the `Helper.getData` function.  There is no way to access it from outside of that function.  If you need to do that, use a member variable, a (`static`) class variable, or pass it to `displaydata` from within `Helper.getData`.

Comment: show me some code to this

Comment: Member variables, class variables, passing arguments around are very basic things that would be covered by any basic tutorial.  They're not specific to Dart or Flutter.

Comment: Using a constructor will help accomplish this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if i got you correctly, you can pass the text to the constructor of the class you want to display the text in it. Hope it helps!

```
void main() {
  String s = Helper.getData('Hello World!');
  DisplayData data = DisplayData(s);
  data.displayText();
} 

class Helper {
  static getData(String someText){
    var text = someText;
    return text;
  }
}

class DisplayData{
    String text;
    DisplayData(this.text);
    void displayText(){
       print(text);
    }


}
```